# Saving in arrays and comparing an argument to an array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, if-statement

I do not know why this code stopped working
I tested it a couple of times and it was running great
what I am trying to do hear is place first and second in 2 different arrays
and then comparing argument $2 ==> $comment to the array varA and if it is in the array i do not want to store it in the text file $file

```
comment=$2
dueD=$3
x=0

hasData()
{
    declare -a varA varB
    cat $file | while IFS=$'\t' read -r num first second;do
         varA+=("$first")
         varB+=("$second")
        done

    if [[ ${varA[@]} == ~$comment ]]; then
        echo "already in the Todo list"
    else
        x=$(cat $file | wc -l)
        x=$(($x+1))
        echo -e "$x\t$comment\t$dueD" >> $file
    fi
```

I think I am storing the values wrong in the array because when I try

```
echo ${varA[@]}
```

nothing gets printed
more over I think my if statement is not accurate enough since this is the 4th time I edit it and it works but after a while it no longer works
need assistance kindly

Comment: Your pipeline creates a sub-shell. Therefore your assignments to `varA` and `varB` happen in the sub-shell and are lost as soon as the sub-shell exits. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for how to do this without a sub-shell.

Comment: Also your `[[` comparison is odd and likely not what you actually want. The `~` on the right-hand side is probably literal (did you mean `=~` for regex comparison)? Also you are matching against the entire contents of `varA` unquoted which means you'll potentially match *between* entries (i.e. the end of one entry and the start of another). If you want to search for entries in the array you need to loop and compare individually or use an associative array (bash 4+). Alternatively don't read the file in at all and use `grep` or similar to check for a match.

Comment: @EtanReisner thanks for the guide lines, but if you can please tell me what praragraph on the link explains the subshells and how to restore them, cause i am not finding it

Comment: Look at the solutions there. See how they don't use a pipe? That's the solution: Don't use a pipe. Use one of the other input redirection options.

Comment: thanks man, i really appreciate your advice, now it is working, decided to save the array into a text file, and then i used grep just like you said to find the comment

Comment: You already have the array in a text file. That's what `$file` **is**. You don't need another one. Also unless you support deleting items from `$file` without renumbering your number column is just the line number in the file and you can probably get rid of it.

Comment: Take a look at process substitution, which will be a way to go in similar cases. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst

Answer (score 0):

Your pipeline creates a sub-shell. Therefore your assignments to `varA` and `varB` happen in the sub-shell and are lost as soon as the sub-shell exits. See [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for how to do this without a sub-shell. – Etan Reisner
Look at the solutions there. See how they don't use a pipe? That's the solution: Don't use a pipe. Use one of the other input redirection options. – Etan Reisner